# Python autocompletion/autosuggestion on GNU/Linux

Tags: python, linux, ide

Assume you imported a package, say unittest2
if you were using Windows IDLE, if you press:
unittest2.
a small help window will pop up and show the list of functions you can use, similarly how can I get this small pop up on linux ?

Am accessing a linux box from putty

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use IDE, then Pycharm should be what you are looking for . Please refer to [download and install it](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/).

If you are using Vim editor, then [python-mode](https://github.com/klen/python-mode) plugin will do all this jobs for you. Please see  this picture:
[image].

Comment: awww am accessing a linux box from putty, no root access to install pycharm though.,.. anyway tnx

Answer (score 1):

Here is a few of many editors you might use in the Linux:

**For python IDE:**

PyCharm: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/auto-completing-code.html

**For generic editors:**

vi/vim: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Any_word_completion

emacs: http://emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoComplete

**BTW, if in the Python interpreter:**

http://conjurecode.com/enable-auto-complete-in-python-interpreter/

Comment: Thanks but its not working, am accessing a linux box from putty

Comment: @Santee Similarly here without root permissions :) I usually install and run these editors (GUI or not) as non-root users, providing necessary system libraries to meet the needs. I use "SSH Secure Shell" or remote access through SSH+Cygwin (for GUI) on Windows.